# Change "Edit with IDLE" default to python 3.X instead of python 2.X on windows

Tags: windows-8, windows-8.1, python, python3

When i right-click a python file in windows, there's normally that "edit with IDLE" option, which is a great help. Unfortunately, on the computer I'm using right now I installed both python 3.4 and python 2.7, and now the "edit with idle" option defaults to python 2.7, instead of what I use more, python 3.4. Is there any way of fixing this issue and changing the "edit with idle" to default to 3.4, short of uninstalling one of them and reinstalling?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update the following registry key to change to a different python version:

`HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Python.File\shell\Edit with IDLE\command`

Comment: Getting an error "cannot edit: error writing the value's new contents" but i guess thats because I'm not being an admin right now

Comment: Fixed it! Lol and i also added an option to "Edit with IDLE 2.7" XD